# Wordscloud in R text mining

Tags: r, frequency, text-mining

When I am passing the given below arguments in R

```
wordcloud(words[1:200], frequency[1:200], min.freq = 70)
wordcloud(words[1:200], frequency[1:200], max.words = 19)
```

It is showing this error:

> Error in if (min.freq > max(freq)) min.freq <- 0 :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

I am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `frequency` contains `NA` values; remove them:

```
wordcloud(words[!is.na(frequency)], freqs[!is.na(frequency)])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you probably have a `NA` in your `frequency` vector. I could replicate your problem with this:

wordcloud(c("test","test2","test20","test200","test2000"),freq=c(75,40,NA,100,10),min.freq=10)